# Insert And Update in One Batch

Tags: java, jdbc

I've scoured the internet for a precise answer without much success. Here is my scenario.

In the JDBC universe, it's standard practice to add several "inserts" OR several "updates" into one statement and execute them as a batch. These are homogenous queries, and it makes perfect sense to batch them. Great!

Now let's consider this case. One transaction constitutes of one "insert" and subsequent other "inserts" to be considered successful. An example would be you have an object Parent_A, that has a list of children [Child_M, Child_N, Child_O,...]. Saving Parent_A requires that you also save the children successfully.

Another slightly different example would be, you have a User U and a child Account A. User U can exist without Account A. But on inserting a new Account A, that is for user U, it is required that you also update User U with the Account info (that would be a transaction).

Given the above two scenarios, is it possible to:
1) Given a list of Parents, can you be able to batch all the queries under one transaction?
2) Given a list of Users, can you be able to insert and update each user with an account in a batch execution, and all under a single transaction?

I hope this is not so verbose!!

Comment: You want to do that with just JDBC or are you open to changing your design to an ORM?

Comment: I want to keep it at JDBC level, unless it gets too hairy

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the [addBatch(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch%28java.lang.String%29) method on Statement.

However, since that requires you to actually build the entire sql string yourself (no use of PreparedStatements/bind variables), it would probably be easier to just do 1 batch execution for each table (i.e. Parent, Child) and only [commit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit%28%29) if all succeed.